# How to retrieve request attributes from a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a basic website where you can add products to a database. The problem is when completing the form for adding a product in the JSP file. I'm able to submit the form but no response is retrieved from the servlet. Once the form is submitted the form is empty again. This happens repeatedly unless I force a FormatNumberException to occur. I've been searching but I couldn't find a solution yet.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Ingrese un producto
    <hr>
    <% if(request.getAttribute("mensaje")!= null){
        out.print(request.getAttribute("mensaje"));
        }
    %>
    <form action="IngresarServlet" method="POST">
        Descripción: <input type="text" name="descr"/><br>
        Precio: <input type="text" name="precio"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>

</body>
```

```
@WebServlet(name = "IngresarServlet", urlPatterns = {"/IngresarServlet"})
public class IngresarServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String descripcion = request.getParameter("descr");
        Double precio = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("precio"));

        Producto p = new Producto(descripcion, precio);

        ProductoDAO dao = new ProductoDAO();
        try {
            dao.insertar(p);
            request.setAttribute("mensaje", "El producto se ha insertado correctamente.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("mensaje", ex.getMessage());
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Ingresar.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your values get inserted in db or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't get inserted. But I can do it via a main class using all the classes that the JSP and the Servlet implement. I mean I tested if I could make the connection to db through the netbeans console and  it worked correctly. I hope I expressed myself correctly.

Comment: I didn't find any thing wrong in your code . can you show your `insertar` method ?